# Can any Functinality of my App can start itself at any point in a day even if my App is not launch/open/start?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-sqlite, xmlpullparser

I am working on an Android app. I need that, at some hour of day. some functionality of my App can start and do its work even if the App is not Started/Launched or opened.

Example:- If i need to parse some xml data from some live feed site. So even if the user doesn't open/launch/start my app,and say some 9:00 in the morning, My App can read those news feeds parse them and save them to my application Database, if the App is installed in the device. The time constraint is not mandatory. But The App should function the way I intend.

I know how to parse and save the data. But can anyone can tell me, whether there is any functionality or any way available that I can use so that My App could do that work even if its not been opened/launch/started.

Sorry for the English. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to launch a service when the app is stopped. This service can read those feed every X time and send a notification (for example).

Read this: [Android: Create service that runs when application stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740593/android-create-service-that-runs-when-application-stops)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best possibility is to use the AlarmManager.
You can set an alarm, which can be received by a broadcast receiver.
From there on you can start a service which parses your xml file.

See: [Android: How to use AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager)

Depending on your needs you may implement a boot-completed-receiver, to restart the alarm
after the device has been rebooted.