# How to run the app without open it in android stoduio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to let part of the app running even if the app terminated. I know how to let it run in the background, but that will not work if the app terminated. What I can do for the part of code I want to let it work even if the app terminated?

Comment: Using ADB with commandline [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076240/install-an-apk-file-from-command-prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076240/install-an-apk-file-from-command-prompt)

Comment: I find your title and description not matching, can you elaborate more? thankyou

Comment: I have installed the apk in my phone, but I want to make a part of the code running even if I close the app for ex. each o'clock the app save something in local database. notice that the service is not the solution because the service work when the app in background not when the app closed. I need something work even if the app closed

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a build to your project, in your app's folder you will have an **apk** file witch you can install it on the device without starting Android Studio.

Your **apk** location is:
ProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk

From command line:

```
adb install example.apk
```

Comment: No No ... I don't mean that, I have installed the apk in my phone, but I want to make a part of the code running even if I close the app
for ex.
each o'clock the app save something in local database

Comment: Ok, I understand.. What you need is a Service. Here is an example of how to use a service : [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: There are many ways in with to use a service, if you get stuck, let me know.

Comment: the service work when the app in background not when the app closed. I need something work even if the app closed ...

Comment: Services work even if you close the app. check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740593/android-create-service-that-runs-when-application-stops

Comment: can I save on SQLite local database from the service ?